# Ruby docs missing stuff

Tags: ruby

This has been bugging me ever since I started learning Ruby five months ago:

Why do the Ruby docs seem to be missing things? For example, http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html has no mention of instance methods `any?` or `all?`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's probably because `any?` and `all?` are methods of `Enumerable`.

See the doc [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F).

There's a section in the sidebar that lists modules included in Array. Enumerable is one (and the only) item in the list.

Comment: Super duper correct, thanks! Do you know of any way to show those inline, so that in the case where multiple modules and perhaps a superclass is present, I wouldn't have to click through each one?

Comment: @fearpi: here's method I use for some years already: http://bit.ly/wzYGaN (link to lmgtfy, for purposes of demonstration :) )

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I was getting really, really confused at why methods seemed to be missing from the docs and started thinking I had totally misunderstood classes! I think they should make this more clear in the documentation in some way. Maybe having the included classes toggle-able in the menu of the class description? I am not stupid and I would think this has confused a lot of beginners!

Comment: @tentimes: you're absolutely right, it was confusing me in the beginning :)